# Comando git push sem efeito aparente

Tags: git

Uma dúvida simples de GIT...

Criei um repositório no servidor remoto e realizei um git remote add (...), git add "arquivos", git commit e git push origin master, em meu localhost, para que eu pudesse me conectar ao repositório e enviar os arquivos. Tudo transcorreu normalmente (mostrou enviando os arquivos e a porcentagem de progresso).

Entretanto, quando vou no meu servidor, não encontro estes arquivos que acabei de realizar o push. Digito ls -la e aparece somente minha pasta .git, que possivelmente contém estes arquivos que enviei.

Ao realizar o push, da maneira que fiz, os arquivos já deveriam estar presentes no servidor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcony procure ver o histórico através do comando

```
git log
```

e verifique se você está enviando para o branch correto, pois haver mais e um. O comando para ver isso é:

```
git branch
```

Answer (score 2):

Se o repositório no servidor é **bare**, isto é, não possui uma **working tree**, seus arquivos não estarão visíveis diretamente no servidor.

A **working tree** do seu repositório são os arquivos de fato. Um repositório em um servidor remoto git não cria esses arquivos, apenas mantém as informações de versão deles, desde a criação do repositório.

Normalmente, a estrutura de arquivos de um servidor remoto git é assim:

```
HEAD        config      description hooks       info        objects     refs
```

Como pode-se ver, os arquivos do repositório não são visíveis.

Se você quiser ter certeza absoluta que seus arquivos foram enviados para o servidor, você pode clonar o repositório em uma nova pasta e verificar se os arquivos são criados.

Dependendo da sua necessidade, você pode também criar um post-commit hook e fazer o checkout dos seus arquivos no servidor. O hook poderia ser algo assim:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/where/to/checkout git checkout -f
```